# Script to check if printer exists locally, and if so, deletes it

Tags: printing, batch-file

I'm writing a windows batch file and need to check whether the print exists on the local computer, and if so, deletes the mapped printer from the computer. Here is the code that I'm using to delete the printer.

```
RUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n \\server\printerName /dn
```

This works fine, but now I need a conditional statement before this so I check if that printer exists first. Then run that line. I'm not sure how to write this.

Comment: Could you not just run it anyways? If it doesn't exist then it won't do anything, if it does then it will delete it?

Comment: I could, but it gives me an error, then proceeds to the next line. I'm running this as a start up script, so I would like it to be error free. Unless this is not an issue (i'm not very experienced with this type of code)

Comment: "Printer connection cannot be removed. Double check the printer name and make sure that the printer is connected to the network."

Comment: Ok, see my answer below, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this, just replace the string to find with the printer you want to find.

```
For /F "Tokens=4 delims=\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Connections ^|find /I "560C"') Do If "%%I"==",,ServerName,HP DeskJet 560C" goto :REMOVE
goto :SKIP
:REMOVE
RUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n \\server\printerName /dn
:SKIP
```

Or just run the command and if it doesn't exist it will error, if it does it will work?

Hope this helps!

Comment: One last thing, sorry to revisit this. How do I run this same code, in the the same script, for a different printer? I tried repeating the lines under the script, but they didn't work this way. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Is this code just not working in your existing script? Or do you need to look for another printer, in which case change the find command to the right one?

Comment: The code I have written is the code you supplied, twice, so that I look for two different printers, one after another. Unfortunately the script only works when I only have one repetition of the code. I'm not sure if i have to put something in between the codes or if it just doesn't work this way.

Comment: Ah right, that will be because of the exits. My existing code would exit after it either worked or didn't. I will edit my answer for you, 2 secs.

Comment: I have edited my answer now. If the printer exists it will goto the :REMOVE line, if it doesn't it will fall onto the next line which will take it past :REMOVE essentially skipping it. Then after :SKIP you can put more code, so if you want to repeat on another printer repeat the code there, just make sure you have different label names, like :REMOVE2 and :SKIP2 or something. Just let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Ah thank you. This has not only fixed my problem, but has been greatly educational. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can just skip the check and run your deletion command anyway.
To suppress the error popup just add the `/q` option as specified in the [rundll32 printui.dll documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057(v=ws.11).aspx).
this yields:

```
RUNDLL32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /n \\server\printerName /dn /q
```